# Why is there a warning on some PoE Switches, non-PoE might suffer damage?

Tags: switch, power-over-ethernet

To my knowledge, the PoE standard requires a Switch to be capable of detecting whether a connected device is PoE capable before delivering the full power via PoE.
Why is there still often a warning, non-PoE Equipment might suffer damage if connected? This seems kind of contradictory to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some poorly designed or constructed devices. We experienced this with some devices that had pins shorted in a way that requested PoE from the switch, but the devices could not handle PoE, and they blew up when connected to a PoE switch interface. This was a design defect in the devices, and we needed to disable PoE on the switch interfaces where those devices were connected.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ron's anwer, some PoE switches support proprietary, pre-standard PoE modes that weren't as thoroughly designed as 802.3af/at. When active, sending power to a device not supporting it gets more likely.

Comment: More to the point, some PoE sources provide a passive form of PoE, where instead of negotiating for power, power is always applied.